# Chain psexec and nunit is not working (psexec exit with code 1 and nunit is crashed)

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, autotest, psexec

Sorry for unclear subject but i really don't understand where problem.

I use a system for autotests c#+webdriver for chrome + nunit (2.6) + cc.net ( 1.6.7981.1)

And my tests is run on remote machine (**Windows XP SP 2 x86**)via psexec which start bat file on remote machine

bat file includes 2 commands:

run msbuild
run nunit-console

Well, psexec has next arguments
/accepteula \MachineName -u Login -p Pass -s Path\start.bat

Bat file has next command
nunit-console-x86.exe "%PROJECT_FOLDER%\Path\Tests.dll" "/xml=%TEST_RESULT_PATH%"

When cc.net launch psexec tests is started and the tests work during some time. Unexpected, psexec exit with code 1

> message level="Error">Path\start.bat exited on MachineName with error code 1. message

But nunit-console on remote machine is continue working

And after some time console is crashed with error

> szAppName : nunit-console-x86.exe     szAppVer : 2.6.0.12051
>   szModName : kernel32.dll     szModVer : 5.1.2600.2180     offset :
>   0001eb33

Message from Event log

> Application: nunit-console-x86.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.IOException Stack:    at
>   System.IO._*Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)    at
>   System.IO.*_ConsoleStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean, Boolean)    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[], Int32, Int32)    at
>   System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(System.String)    at
>   System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(System.String, System.Object)    at
>   System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(System.String,
>   System.Object)    at System.Console.WriteLine(System.String,
>   System.Object)    at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(System.String[]) 
>   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Class1.Main(System.String[])

If run nunit locally than no problem(nunit-console works fun).

Some time ago system worked, and i don't know what is changed (This is most bad case)

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved!
Now system is working

Comment: Care to share the knowledge of your fix?